# How to create a file to test Zip Slip Vulnerability from commandline

Tags: zip

From https://snyk.io/research/zip-slip-vulnerability

> The contents of this zip file have to be hand crafted. Archive
>   creation tools don’t typically allow users to add files with these
>   paths, despite the zip specification allowing it. However, with the
>   right tools, it’s easy to create files with these paths.

I want to create a test payload so that i can check few of my zip handling logic. But i cant find any leads on how to create one.

```
:~/Desktop # touch "../../../../../../../../tmp/evil.sh"
:~/Desktop # ll
:~/Desktop # ll /tmp/evil.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 14 09:27 /tmp/evil.sh
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe

```
zip zipslip.zip ../../../../../../../../tmp/evil.sh
```

Comment: I know that this post might be long overdue but I tried it and got an "zip warning: name not matched. Zip error: nothing to do!" error message.

Comment: @ThomasWest Make sure the file exists at the path (on your system) you're trying to zipslip to (on the remote system).

Answer (score 0):

Most pen-testers use this library to test this:
https://github.com/ptoomey3/evilarc

It hasn't been updated in 12 years, but... doesn't really need to be (look at the pull requests or forks to see updated versions to support python3 / etc if interested).

From the description:

- Create archive containing a file with directory traversal
- python evilarc.py [input file] [options]

Options available:

- --output-file / -f: File to output archive to.  Archive type is based off of file extension.  Supported extensions are zip, jar, tar, tar.bz2, tar.gz, and tgz.  Defaults to evil.zip.
- --depth / -d: Number directories to traverse. Defaults to 8.
- --os / -o: OS platform for archive (win|unix). Defaults to win.
- --path / -p: Path to include in filename after traversal.  Ex: WINDOWS\System32\

Example usage based on what you are targeting:

`$ python evilarc.py evil.sh -f payload.zip -p ../../../../../../../../tmp/ -d 0 -o unix`